# scrollbar does not appear

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

So the scrollbar is not showing when entering the page, it only appears if using mouse scroll
I already tried to put:
z index: 10

overflow: roll

!important

But none worked, it still has the same bug, I don't know what it could be. I'm using plugin-perfect-scrollbar.scss in version 1.4.0

Container

```css
.ps {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

scrollbar

```css
.ps__rail-x {
  display: none;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
  height: 15px;
  /* there must be 'bottom' or 'top' for ps__rail-x */
  bottom: 0px;
  /* please don't change 'position' */
  position: absolute;
}

.ps__rail-y {
  display: none;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, opacity .2s linear;
  width: 15px;
  /* there must be 'right' or 'left' for ps__rail-y */
  right: 0;
  /* please don't change 'position' */
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: you have tried overflow: scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `overflow: scroll;` then you can insert a manual scrollbar by adding `::-webkit-scrollbar` in your CSS. Meaning - wherever there is a scrollbar or an `overflow: scroll;` these styles will take effect.

Mini demonstration below:

```css
div {
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px #ffd110;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>DIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIV<br>DIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIVDIV</p>
</div>
```